# Trying to install Phatch getting dependency issues regarding blender, try to install blender more dependency issues

Tags: dependencies, blender

So I am trying to install the latest version of Phatch using the .deb for ubuntu available on their site and installing through the Ubuntu Software center. I get the message "Cannot install blender".

So I try to install blender (still in USC) and I get the following:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
blender: Depends: libavcodec-extra-52 (>= 4:0.6-1~) but 4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
         Depends: libavdevice-extra-52 (>= 4:0.6-1~) but 4:0.6.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libavformat-extra-52 (>= 4:0.6-1~) but 4:0.6.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libavutil-extra-50 (>= 4:0.6-1~) but 4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
         Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: libjpeg62 (>= 6b1) but 6b1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.5) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: libswscale-extra-0 (>= 4:0.6-1~) but 4:0.6.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu3 is to be installed

When I try to install any of the missing packages in Synaptic it fails: for example 


libavdevice-extra-52:
  Depends: libavcodec-extra-52 (<4:0.6.1-99) but 4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 Depends: libavformat-extra-52 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libavformat-extra-52 but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: libavutil-extra-50 (<4:0.6.1-99) but 4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

It also wants to uninstall a lot of programs including audacity, vlc etc.

So is it actually possible to install blender and therfor Phatch on Ubuntu 11.04 and if so how?

Comment: Could someone with more rep than me please add the tag "Phatch" to this question. I don't have enough rep to create new tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the phatch package from the 11.04 repository, that's the most current one (0.2.7.1-1).

Some of the packages are too old for 11.04 but look like they are for 10.04, e.g. libavdevice-extra-52 and libavformat-extra-52.

Maybe you don't have the multiverse channel enabled and the packages are still there from before you upgraded an older version.

If you type

```
 apt-cache policy libavdevice-extra-52
```

in a Terminal window that tells you where the package is from.

Comment: When I try to install from Synaptic I get "phatch:
 Depends: phatch-cli but it is not going to be installed" and when I try installing phatch-cli I get" phatch-cli:
 Depends: python-pyexiv2 but it is not going to be installed" So I installed python-pyexiv2 which went ok then I went back to install Phatch again with the error message saying it needs phatch-cli. When I try to install phatch-cli it wants to remove python-pyexiv2 which I just installed!

Comment: output from: apt-cache policy libavdevice-extra-52: "libavdevice-extra-52:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:0.6.1-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4:0.6.1-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://debian.nctu.edu.tw/ubuntu/ natty/multiverse i386 Packages"    I then went to install it using apt-get:   "libavdevice-extra-52:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:0.6.1-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4:0.6.1-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://debian.nctu.edu.tw/ubuntu/ natty/multiverse i386 Packages" So it looks like I have somehow ended up with broken packages

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get install -f to fix the broken packages and nothing happened:   "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Comment: It looks like your mirror didn't get any updates since  2011-Feb-27 so you are using natty from a few days before alpha3. Use another mirror.